# Linking error while using dlib with libjpeg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, machine-learning, libjpeg, linker-errors

I am studying Machine Learning and  Pattern Recognition and using `dlib` library for that. I was trying one example `code face_detection_ex.cpp` provided with the library. I created a separate project under Visual Studio 2010 and included the `face_detection_ex.cpp` example and `dlib\all\source.cpp` files. It build fine. But, if I enable `DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` by

```
#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
```

then it will throw the linking error `LNK2019` for all the functions of `libjpeg` library used by the `dlib` library. I tried `#pragma comment(lib, libjpeg)` and I also tried to include the library in project properties, but still the same.

After spending 1 day on this error, I switched to linux and try to work in that. But there also I am getting the same linking errors.

Then on the `dlib` release-note I read that `libjpeg` library is included in dlib's external folder and use dlib's `cmake` file for the example code and `cmake` will perform the static linking. I tried that and with `cmake` it is linking. I tried to find out how the linking is happening as I want it to work with visual studio and other compilers also but I couldn't find out why the `libjpeg` library is unable to link.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: [Here](http://dlib.net/compile.html) it is mentioned how to use `dlib` with Visual Studio. And how to compile the example on linux. So, as I have to link with `libjpeg` library, I added the `-ljpeg` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMake to generate a Visual Studio project that is properly configured and that's the easiest way to do this if you want to use Visual Studio.

However, if you really want to configure the Visual Studio project by hand then all you need to do is add the files in the dlib/external/libjpeg folder to your Visual Studio project and also add the dlib/external/libjpeg folder to the include search path.